# Editing Managed Metadata List columns using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to update a list outside of my app web. When I find the list, I am finding my column, then casting that into a TaxonomyField. The purpose of casting is to be able to play with `get_termGuid()` which would then let me get to `set_termGuid`.

The following works just fine, but I'm not getting the results that I am expecting. 
`myField.get_typeDisplayName()` gives me 'Managed Metadata'

but using `taxFieldValue.get_termGuid()` gives me "". So when I attempt to load taxFieldValue, I get

> 'Object doesn't support property or method 'get_$19_0''

Something seems off, what am I missing here? Most of the samples that I have seen out there are for getting the value of a specific list item. What I am trying to do is alter the Term Store Settings for a specific list column. Not seeing too much out there on that.

*edit* also, I was then looking at what the process is for creating a new list column using JavaScript and noticed that the only option for this type of column is addFieldAsXml. So that did not help out my situation any.

```
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));    
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
siteUrl = hostweburl + '/' + url;
var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, siteUrl);    
oWeb = hostcontext.get_web();    
oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(title);

listFields = oList.get_fields();  

myField = listFields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("ACKeyWord");    
taxField = clientContext.castTo(myField, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);     
taxFieldValue = taxField.getFieldValueAsTaxonomyFieldValue();    

clientContext.load(oList);    
clientContext.load(myField);
clientContext.load(taxField);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onListFieldsSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onListFieldsFailed));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to manage [TaxonomyField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312495(v=office.15).aspx) properties there is no need to utilize [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.getFieldValueAsTaxonomyFieldValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312521(v=office.15).aspx)

The following example demonstrates how to print `TaxonomyField` specific properties

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();    
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);    

ctx.load(field);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        var taxField = ctx.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);

        //print Taxonomy Field specific properties
        console.log(taxField.get_sspId().toString().toString());
        console.log(taxField.get_anchorId().toString());
        console.log(taxField.get_termSetId().toString());
    },  
    function (sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```